# Call different archive page based on post type

Tags: custom-post-types, archives

Ok, I have quite a few CPT's on my latest project.  Most of the CPT's are only used to display metabox content linking to pdfs, etc.  I looked around and couldn't find quite what I was looking for, but thought I could setup a function that calls the standard archive.php template if the post type is "posts" and if not it could call the archive-cpt.php file.

If anyone has seen something like that, or has set something like that up and wouldn't mind sharing their code, it would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at the [Template Hierarchy section of the Codex that concerns Custom Post types](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy#Custom_Post_Types_display).

> 1. archive-{post_type}.php - If the post type were product, WordPress would
>      look for archive-product.php.
> 2. archive.php
> 3. index.php

What you are describing is built in, down to the file naming pattern-- `archive-cpt.php`

To load the same template for all CPT archives use:

```
function not_post_archive_wpse_107931($template) {
  if (is_post_type_archive()) {
    $template = get_stylesheet_directory().'/archive-cpt.php';
  }
  return $template;
}
add_filter('template_include','not_post_archive_wpse_107931');
```

That will hijack all CPT archives so I would be very careful with it. It could lead to great frustration if someone can't figure out why a CPT archive is not loading the expected template.

Barely tested. Possibly buggy. Caveat emptor. No refunds.

Comment: Well, what I'm not wanting to do is create an archive-{post_type}.php template for each CPT.  I'd like to use one archive-cpt.php file for all CPT's.  Since they don't fall under "posts" I wasn't sure if there was a way to assign an archive-cpt.php file to any registered post type that is not "Posts"

Comment: Give me a minute. You can do that with a filter.

Comment: Awesome!  I thought I could but wasn't sure.  Seems like it might be an easier way to go if there are multiple CPT's.  Plus my client who can't create templates (at least I don't trust them to) can then create new CPT's via a plugin I've installed.

Comment: Tried that filter, but now all archive pages are coming up blank.  I'll keep playing with it.  Thanks for the start!

Comment: I'm an idiot. Sorry. I think you want `get_template_directory` not `get_template_directory_uri`

Comment: I was just looking into that!  You beat me to it though, thanks again!  Works Now:

  function not_post_archive_wpse_107931($template) {
     if (is_post_type_archive()) {
     $template = get_stylesheet_directory().'/archive-cpt.php';
     }
     return $template;
     }
             add_filter('template_include','not_post_archive_wpse_107931');