# pre_get_post alter current post id

Tags: plugin-development, query-posts, pre-get-posts

For some purpose, we want to apply a change to the **Wordpress** flow that affect's **WooCommerce** product page being displayed.

When a product page is displayed (e.g. www.mysite.com/?**product=my-product**), traditionally, it displays the post of "my-product", we want to intercept that and do the following:

1) Display a predefined page instead of the "my-product" page (modify current $post to be something constant, e.g. page with ID=1 or by slug name).

2) Maintain the $product setup so the current product being referred to is still "my-product", in other words, does not interfere with WooCommerce setup.

I'm trying the following

```
public function pre_get_posts_custom($wc_query) {

    if ( !$wc_query->is_main_query() /* || is_product_page() */ ) {
        return;
    }

    $wc_query-> set( 'page_id' , 1);
    $wc_query-> set( 'pagename' , 'pageslug');
    $wc_query-> set( 'post_type' , 'page');

    return;
}
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'pre_get_posts_custom', 999);
```

But that's not working, it is referring me to:
www.mysite.com/?product=my-product&page_id=1 which ends up showing a not found page.

Ideas?

Comment: Why not use `template_include` to load your template? Something like: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/107933/21376 Or this: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/127345/21376

Comment: Template is not the issue here, it is the $post variable that refers to the post of the product ("my product") and not the page I want ("id = 1"). I want to tweak other plugins right from the start so that they think the page that is loaded is id=1.